# Problem of basic probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

We have 6 machines; the lifetime of each is  ~ $\exp(-\ln(.7)=0.35)$ if one machine fail it is repair the next day .What is the probability that some particular day NO machine works??

So far I got : If the lifetime of the machine is greater that the particular day the probability $= 0$. I also think to separate the even days of the not even 
Is this the right path ??

Comment: I don't understand this question... what is ~ $exp(-ln(.7)=0.35)$ mean?  If a machine fails is it running the next day or is it out for 2 days each time?

Comment: The lifetime of each machine distributed like an exponential with parameter lambda=0.35 ,the problem just says what I wrote

Comment: I still don't get what you're asking... by 'some particular day' do you mean eventually there will be a day where no machine works?  Cuz that will eventually happen with probability 1.  Or given day $x$ what is the probability that no machine works?

Comment: What is the probability that ONE machine fails on day 1?

Comment: I mean, given a particular machine, what is the probability that it fails on the first day?  Also, after it is repaired, what is that machine's life distribution?  Does it start again as if it were brand new?

Comment: I also have those questions but I think I have to find :.given day x what is the probability that no machine works given that after each machine fails it is repair and start like a brand new  we should consider X1,2,..6 Are independent because we have also prove that whe they are not the probability changes

Comment: ok if that is the interpretation we're going with then that is a VERY hard problem... which makes me think it's not the intended interpretation, but I don't know what it could be given the wording... sorry...

Comment: How would be more easy to solve??