# probability challenge

Tags: probability

"Plinko” is a very popular game on The Price is Right. In order to win the top prize of $\$50,000,$ a contestant has to win five Plinko chips and insert each one into a $\$10,000$ slot.

A contestant is given one chip free and has to earn the remaining four. 
To win an additional Plinko chip, a contestant has to guess the price of an item from two choices. 
There are nine slots in which a Plinko chip can fall: $2$ are worth $\$0$, $2$ are worth $\$100$, $2$ are worth $\$500$, $2$ are worth $\$1000$, and $1$ is worth $\$10,000.$

Find the probability of a contestant winning the $\$50,000$ prize in Plinko (Hint: take into account the contestant has to win four additional chips when calculating the probability).

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Do you have any thoughts on the problem that you can share? Regards

Answer (score 1):

If we assume all probability distributions are uniform, there is a $.5^4$ chance that the contestant wins the extra $4$ chips, and a $(1/9)^5$ chance that each Plinko chip falls in the $10,000$ slot.  This gives a total probability of:

$$.5^4\cdot\left(\frac{1}{9}\right)^5\approx.0000011$$

This means a contestant will win $50,000$ dollars $1$ out of every $944784$ tries.

The Wikipedia article says the Price is Right has aired about $7500$ shows, and assuming a Plinko game is played on each show (is this true?), the probability that a maximum win occurs in $7500$ plays is:

$$1-\left(1-.5^4\cdot\left(\frac{1}{9}\right)^5\right)^{7500}\approx.0079$$

So probably no one has ever pulled this off, and probably no one ever will.

Now, I think that there is a greater than fifty percent chance a contestant wins a particular Plinko chip, and depending on the mechanics of the board, perhaps a greater than one in nine chance that the chip falls in the $10,000$ slot, so a maximum win may actually be more common than I've calculated.

Comment: could you look at my question please ?? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/418964/problem-of-basic-probability?noredirect=1#comment895687_418964